# SpringBoot application ignore xml configuration for HibernateValidator

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

My question is the following:

Is it possible to ignore XML configuration for HibernateValidator, i.e. exclude validation.xml parsing in a SpringBoot application?

I do not have the need for a validation.xml in my application, but I see that when the application starts up, it tries to parse this file.
I found this in the Hibernate Validator documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html):

> It is even possible to ignore the XML configuration completely via Configuration.ignoreXmlConfiguration().

What I see is, that in the ***LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()*** method, the configuration is created for the validator. This bean has a method called ***postProcessConfiguration(Configuration configuration)***, which is called before the validatorFactory is built from the configuration.
It seemed an ideal place to call the ignoreXmlConfiguration() method, what the documentation suggested.

I tried to extend this LocalValidatorFactoryBean, so that I can implement this call in the above mentioned method. Then I tried to load this bean via java configuration class.

Unfortunately some bootstrapping mechanism already uses the Spring provided bean, before it finds mine, the two beans run at the same time. I saw the message saying that XML configuration is ignored the with the bean I created, however, this solution did not help, because the Spring provided bean is not substituted with mine.

I also tried to find if there is any application property that I can use, or exclude some autoconfiguration, but no luck.

Any ideas? :)

**UPDATE:**
I tried excluding the HibernateJPAAutoConfiguration, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need hibernate validator then remove all dependency related to hibernate validator from pom.xml file.
you can also try @EnableAutoConfiguration(excludes=) annotation adding on your Application class to exclude default validation configuration.

like @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class} })

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do need the hibernate validator , so removing the dependency is not an option. I tried excluding the HibernateJPAAutoconfiguration, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: if you have validation.xml in your applications classpath,just remove that and then spring boot will automatically configure HibernateValidator as default validator for your application as soon as it finds jar for that.

Comment: I don't have validation.xml, but when the validatorFactory is built, the **org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory()** tries to parse the XML configuration. This is the behavior I try to exclude, because is it unnecessary.
During the parsing the first thing it checks is whether the ignoreXmlConfiguration flag is true or false. I would be nice, if somehow I could set this flag to false, that would solve my problem.

Comment: I meant to write that I want to set the ignoreXmlConfiguration flag to true.

Comment: default value for this flag is already false.

check in this class

org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl

private boolean ignoreXmlConfiguration = false;

also parseValidationXml() first check if validation.xml file is present or not,then only it will parse the file and as you said you dont have that xml file then i guess the default behaviour for validator configuration is fine